# My JavaScript doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript, and I've included JS at the bottom of my HTML page. I checked the selectors, actions and everything seems to match. However, when I try to use JS functionality nothing seems to happen; as if there is no JS at all.

Tried checking if the selectors and actions are valid. Tried checking if I included the script tags within my  tag.

```
const navBtn = document.getElementById("nav-btn");
const navBar = document.getElementById("navbar");
const navClose = document.getElementById("close");

navBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
 navBar.classList.add("showNav");
});
navClose.addEventListener("click", () => {
 navBar.classList.remove("showNav");
});

.showNav {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.close {
  color: var(--mainWhite);
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close:hover {
  color: var(--mainDark);
  padding-left: 0.2rem;
}
```

Complete project can be found here for more information: https://github.com/aleblok70/website.

Desired result was to include action on click transform: translateX(0); actual results were that nothing happens on click.

Comment: You can find out a great deal about what is going on in a situation like this by using `console.log()` to verify what is happening. For example, you might add a `console.log(navBtn,navBar,navClose)` after your constants to verify you are finding the correct elements or modify your event listener with: `(e) => {console.log(e);` to see what events are actually firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the listener to the element based on an id -

```
const navClose = document.getElementById("close");
```

but your styling is based on a class - is this correct?

```
.close {..}
```

These need to be the same - so if the id is correct then it should be

```
#close {
  color: var(--mainWhite);
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#close:hover {
  color: var(--mainDark);
  padding-left: 0.2rem;
}
```

Comment: Should have added one more id value in my HTML. Thanks, this solved the problem.

Comment: happy to help - have fun coding :)